# Functions in two variables satisfying $f_{xy} f = f_x f_y$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

What is the family of analytic functions $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy the condition$f_{xy} f = f_{x} f_{y}$? Is there any interesting significance to this condition?

This holds for any   function of the form $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$. Are there any other possibilities?

The condition is equivalent to saying that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \log (f) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \log (f_y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your last equation, it's also equivalent to $$\frac{d}{dx}[\log(f_y)-\log(f)]=\frac{d}{dx}\log(f_y/f) =0. $$ Thus $\log(f_y/f)$ is independent of $x$, i.e., $f_y/f=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\log f$ is a function of $y$ alone. This implies that $\log f(x,y)=G(x)+H(y)$ for functions $G,H$, which is equivalent to $f(x,y)$ being separable.

A more symmetric presentation: Recalling the quotient rule, the relation $f_x f_y = f_{xy}f$ implies

$$(\log f)_{xy}=(f_x/f)_y=\frac{f_{xy}f-f_x f_y}{f^2}=0$$ which again implies $\log f(x,y)=G(x)+H(y)$.